# Entity Framework 5 with Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5

I am looking for the simplest, best-practice approach to building a web app using EF database-first approach and the MVC 4.5/Web API.  My application will use the angular framework to make ajax calls to retrieve json data on demand.

Currently, I'm getting excessive and ill-structured data in response to my api calls and would like to know how to go about cleaning that up.

The application will provide job tracking so I have tables like:

```
Person
    Id
    Name
    Email
    Department : FK -> Department

Department
    Id
    Name

Jobs
    Id
    RequestedBy : FK -> Person
    AssignedTo  : FK -> Person

JobHistory
    Id
    JobId : FK -> Jobs
```

So, ideally when I call

```
$http.get(/api/People)
```

I'd get:

```
[{Name: 'alice', Email: 'alice@here.com', Department: 'ABC'},
 {Name: 'bob',   Email: 'bob@here.com',   Department: 'CDE'}]
```

I suppose this means that *normally* the principal entities will be eagerly loaded but not all the other tables with dependencies to Person. But there will be times when I want to use those back references to get all the jobs an individual may be working on or or has requested.

If possible, I'd rather not have to resort to things like modifying the T4 templates.  While that is clever, it is not very flexible.  Also, I dislike the idea of being given a power tool and told that I have to study the schematics and rewire the insides before using it.  I'm not a professional developer and really want to focus on the job, not the tool;  Linq2Sql was very good for that.  Of course, if modifying the innards is the right answer, I'll take it.

This seems like such a straightforward use of the Web API I feel sure I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks

**Edit**
Additional info that is most likely causing part of my problem.  At some point, to get the above to work, I added the following to Global.asax.cs:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
```

With eager loading, the two fields in Jobs that refer to Person result in a circular reference.  The above code allows Json.Net to serialize it but fills the json with unwanted data.  I believe the solution is to somehow switch to lazy loading but can this be done in the database first approach?

Comment: I suppose you have gone through all tutorials, etc? See here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/using-web-api-with-entity-framework,-part-1

Comment: Yes, the tutorials are good.  It is not that it does not work.  The problem is that the json I get back looks like:  `{$id: "1", $values: [{$id: "2", Departments: {$id: "3", Jobs: {$id: "4", $values: []}, People: { $id: "5", $values: [{ $ref: "2" }, { $id: "6", Departments: { $ref: "3" }, Jobs: { $id: "7", $values: [{ $id: "8",  ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, oddly enough, to get lazy loading to work with database first, I had to set the "Lazy Loading Enabled" to false in the properties of the ConceptualEntityModel.

I then added

`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;`

in Application_Start() and removed the PreserveReferencesHandling as mentioned above in the question.  That gave me the clean json I wanted from my model.

One difficulty still remains but barring a better response, I will work around it.  In my PersonRepository I use:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetAll() {
return db.People
    .Include("C_Departments")
    .AsNoTracking();
}
```

To get the people along with their Departments.  Unfortunately, if there is a navigation property in the Departments entity pointing back to people, it eagerly loads all members of the department along with the department info.  In other words, at the .Include, lazy loading stops again.